# Schwarzschild metric in a different coordinate system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity

In PADMANABHAN, Gravitation (Foundations and Frontiers), Cambridge, p
 $304$, exercice $7.6$, an example of the Schwarzschild metric in a
 different coordinate system is given :

$$\mbox{d}s^2= -c^2\mbox{d}T^2 +
 \dfrac{4}{9}\left(\frac{9GM}{2(R-cT)}\right)^ {\large \frac{2}{3}}
 \mbox{d}   R^2+\left(\frac{9GM}{2}(R-cT)^2\right)^ {\large
 \frac{2}{3}} \mbox{d}\Omega^2 \tag{7.52}$$

The second part of the exercise is :

> "Consider observers located at fixed spatial coordinates. Show that
>   they are on a free fall trajectory starting with zero velocity at
>   infinite distances and that $T$ represents their proper time. This
>   provides a simple interpretation of this coordinate system"

I am afraid I don't really know how precisely to see this...

Comment: Try looking for a conversion from this coordinate system back into Schwarzschild coordinates.

Comment: If any of our full time relativists could answer this I'd be very interested to see the answer. I'm guessing that T and R are the rain coordinates (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gullstrand%E2%80%93Painlev%C3%A9_coordinates#Rain_coordinates) but my attempts to find the appropriate transformations have covered several sheets of paper with much scribble but little information.

Comment: @JohnRennie: I'll give it a try at lunch.  This looked like a textbook problem, so I thought I'd just give Trimok a push along, but if it's actually looking nontrivial, I'm certainly interested in something fun to do.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer: thanks. I have Padmanabhan's book but he doesn't give any solutions for the exercises and Googling hasn't found any solution sheets.

Comment: @JohnRennie : It is ok, I  found the metrics  :$ds^2 = -(1 - \frac{2Gm}{r})dT^2+dr^2+2\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\frac{MG}{r}} c~dT~dr+r^2 d\Omega^2$, by  simply choosing $r^2 = \left(\frac{9GM}{2}(R-cT)^2\right)^ {\large
 \frac{2}{3}}$

Comment: @JerrySchirmer : I think I understand the free falling observer, because, at fixed $R$ (and $\Omega$), $T$ appears as a proper time (and, in fact, after the above transformation, we find Gullstrand–Painlevé coordinates), but I am not sure to have understood the " starting with zero velocity at infinite distances"

Comment: @Trimok: yes, so now, you know that $g_{tt}$ is in its final form.  So, you know you have to eliminate the cross term, so you have to find some function $f(r)$ such that $T = t + f(r)$, and where $g_{tr}$ vanishes, and you're done.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer : I had no problem,following [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gullstrand%E2%80%93Painlev%C3%A9_coordinates#Rain_coordinates), to see the relation between standard Schwarzschild metrics and   the formulation with Gullstrand–Painlevé coordinates. My problem was about velocity . If I follow Wikipedia, the free-falling observer "rain-frame" has a relative velocity of $\beta = - \sqrt{\frac{2M}{R}}$ relatively to the "shell-frame". So, is it the same velocity Padmanabhan is speaking about ?

Comment: @Trimok: you've solved for $t(T,R)$ and $r(T,R)$.  the question presupposes that you're at constant $R$.  Find the timelike curve that corresponds to this, and then find $v = \frac{\dot r}{\dot t}$

Comment: @JerrySchirmer : OK. I finally found, when $r \to \infty$ , a dependence  of $|v|$ in $r^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, so all seems OK. Thanks.